# DNS leak: Looking up own hostname with DNS queries

Tags: dns, proxy, arch-linux, wireshark, hostname

I was checking a proxied program for DNS leaks with tshark when I noticed this:

```
13.170066    10.0.2.15 -> 192.168.1.1  DNS 66 Standard query 0xd473  A [hostname]
13.753496    10.0.2.15 -> 192.168.1.1  DNS 66 Standard query 0x7bb4  A [hostname]
```

where [hostname] is the hostname of the machine the program and tshark  are running on, 10.0.2.15 is the local machine, and 192.168.1.1 is the router.

Why does the computer look up its own hostname and how can I prevent this from leaking information about the computer?

Note that changing the hostname once is not useful since an (untrusted) proxy knows that it is the same computer connecting every time since the computer sends the same hostname.

(crossposted from [ask.wireshark.org](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/18469/dns-leak-looking-up-own-hostname-with-dns-queries))

Comment: Can you fix this by hardcoding 10.0.2.15 [hostname] into your hosts file ?  Hopefully this would stop the lookup leaking out your local machine ?

Comment: What are you afraid is "leaking" here? That it is asking for it's own IP address? Your system should have some kind of local name cache, so it shouldn't ask too often anyway. Re @davidgo's suggestion, don't hard-wire names that way. If DHCP sees fit to assign another IP address next month, things will fail in mystifying ways, and you'd have forgotten about this kludge.

Comment: @vonbrand I am afraid that the hostname is leaking. If I connect to a proxy and query my hostname, the proxy can map my hostname to the data sent during the connection. Later, if I connect to the same proxy (through intermediate proxies) it knows that the data sent in the new connection was sent from the same machine that sent the previous data. BTW It actually looks up the hostname almost every time I run a test program (firefox on google.com).

Comment: @davidgo , vonbrand:  Are there any disadvantages to hardcoding the hostname to 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: If you are worried to _that_ measure, better look into stuff like tor <http://www.torproject.org>. Nothing you could knit at home will give you enough assurance (but even tor has had it's vulnerabilities...)

Comment: @vonbrand lol Actually the proxy I am using at the moment (to do all these tests) *is* tor. Sending my data through three servers is not very useful if the exit node has my name ;)

Comment: Navin - Yes, as @vonbrand says, if your IP address changes you may experience problems correctly resolving your machines name.  If you use static IP addressing (or even dynamically assign a static IP address for your PC using DHCP), there is nothing wrong with doing that.  There are differing thoughts around hardcoding a hostname to 127.0.0.1, but this is done quite often in practice.  Have a look at http://www.leonardoborda.com/blog/127-0-1-1-ubuntu-debian/